# Google Calendar API V3 - New events are not returned

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am working on a Windows 8 app which is using Google Calendar API V3.
Until last week, I was able to add and retrieve events of my agenda directly from this App.

But, for no reason, the Google Calendar API doesn't send me anymore new events and events that I've added recently in my agenda even if I add an event directly from the Google Calendar website. Hovewer, I still receive old events.

I use this request : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list and get the same result in their generator and in my apps. 
Does someone have an idea of what is going on ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet by any chance?

Comment: Still not :/ It's a very random behavior, sometimes it works, sometimes not :/

Answer (score 1):

I think,it is related to pagination issue once try to set **maxResults** parameter or use **pageToken** parameter

Answer (score 0):

Please check the calendar permissions first.

Comment: I dit it but everything is ok. Some events that was returned last week are not returned anymore. I am wondering if there are some restrictions but can't find something relevant.